# No output in xcode

Tags: objective-c

Hi i`m starting to develop in objective c, but when I try to show a simple message , there´s no output i only have this class main.m

## import

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"%@",@"Hello, World!");    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint on your log statement and report back whether or not it is even being hit.  What you've shown thus far should work if your app is configured properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget it it was the keyboard that was bad configured.

Answer (score 2):

This should be working, is your debugger showing?

[image]